# Шаблон класса в Intellij Idea

Tags: классы, intellij-idea, шаблоны

При создании нового класса, IDEA генерирует определённый стандартный текст в виде комментария. Как его изменить/отключить создание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`settings -> Editor -> File add Code Templates` и там появится список файлов и шаблонов применяемых к ним..и там уже редактируешь шаблоны при создании как пожелаешь
надо было на английском в поиске написать template ;-)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]